# Running JDK self extracting .bin file stuck with python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, installation, java, self-extracting

I trying to run JDK self extracting .bin file via python subprocess,

Here is the code

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('./jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin', cwd=installdir,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

it runs and stuck , output showing below:

```
Install jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin ...
Unpacking...
```

the bin file is able to run independently in terminal

I turn on the shell debug by

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('sh -x ./jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin', cwd=installdir,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

output as below

```
Install jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin ...
Unpacking...

+ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

Checksumming...

+ umask 022

Extracting...

+ javahome=jdk1.6.0_45

UnZipSFX 5.50 of 17 February 2002, by Info-ZIP (Zip-Bugs@lists.wku.edu).

+ platform=linux

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/

+ PACKED_JARS='jre/lib/rt.jar jre/lib/jsse.jar jre/lib/charsets.jar lib/tools.jar jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar jre/lib/plugin.jar jre/lib/javaws.jar jre/lib/deploy.jar'

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/

+ ARCH=32

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/

+ BINARY_NAME=jdk-6u45-fcs-bin-b06-linux-i586-26_mar_2013.bin

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/java

+ diskSpaceRequired=230500

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/keytool

++ uname -s

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/policytool

+ '[' Linux = Linux ']'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/rmiregistry

+ tail_args=-n

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/rmid

+ outname=install.sfx.5699

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/tnameserv

++ df -k .

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/orbd

++ awk '{if ( $4 ~ /%/) { print $3 } else { print $4 } }'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/servertool

++ tail -n -1

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/unpack200

+ diskSpace=540468

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/pack200

+ '[' 540468 -lt 230500 ']'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/jcontrol

+ trap 'rm -f $outname; exit 1' HUP INT QUIT TERM

    linking: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/ControlPanel  -> ./jcontrol

+ echo Unpacking...

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/java_vm

+ tail -n +146 ./jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/javaws

+ '[' -x /usr/bin/sum ']'

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/

+ echo Checksumming...

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/applet/

++ /usr/bin/sum install.sfx.5699

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/

+ sum='01464 70113'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar

+ index=1

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar

+ for s in '$sum'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar

+ case $index in

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack

+ sum1=01464

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext/meta-index

+ index=2

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/

+ for s in '$sum'

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/

+ case $index in

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/native_threads/libhpi.so

+ sum2=70113

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/

+ index=3

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so

+ '[' 01464 -ne 01464 ']'

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/Xusage.txt

+ '[' 70113 -ne 70113 ']'

    linking: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/server/libjsig.so  -> ../libjsig.so

+ chmod +x install.sfx.5699

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/libsaproc.so

+ echo Extracting...

   creating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client/

+ ./install.sfx.5699

  inflating: jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
```

I also capture the self extract script of bin file  by

```
head -145 jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin
```

From the script and debug log , I can see it just stuck at line 74 of extract script

```
echo "Extracting..."
./$outname
```

full script as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
umask 022

release_comp() {
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ] ; then
    echo "eq"
    else
    lrel=`printf "%s\n%s\n" $1 $2 | \
        sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k 5,5n | \
        head -1`
        if [ "$1" = "${lrel}" ]; then
            echo "lt"
        else
            echo "gt"
        fi
    fi
}


install_JavaDB() {
    return 0
}

javahome=jdk1.6.0_45
platform=linux
PACKED_JARS="jre/lib/rt.jar jre/lib/jsse.jar jre/lib/charsets.jar lib/tools.jar jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar jre/lib/plugin.jar jre/lib/javaws.jar jre/lib/deploy.jar"
ARCH=32
BINARY_NAME=jdk-6u45-fcs-bin-b06-linux-i586-26_mar_2013.bin
diskSpaceRequired=230500
if [ "`uname -s`" = "Linux" ]; then
    tail_args="-n"
fi

outname=install.sfx.$$
diskSpace=`df -k . | tail ${tail_args} -1 | awk '{if ( $4 ~ /%/) { print $3 } else { print $4 } }'`
if [ $diskSpace -lt $diskSpaceRequired ]; then
    printf "You will need atleast %s kBytes of Disk Free\n" $diskSpaceRequired
    printf "Please free up the required Disk Space and try again\n"
    exit 3
fi
trap 'rm -f $outname; exit 1' HUP INT QUIT TERM
echo "Unpacking..."
tail ${tail_args} +146 "$0" > $outname
if [ -x /usr/bin/sum ]; then
    echo "Checksumming..."

    sum=`/usr/bin/sum $outname`
    index=1
    for s in $sum; do
        case $index in
            1)
                sum1=$s;
                index=2;
                ;;
            2)
                sum2=$s;
                index=3;
                ;;
        esac
    done
    if [ $sum1 -ne 01464 ] || [ $sum2 -ne 70113 ]; then
        echo "The download file appears to be corrupted.  Please refer"
        echo "to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation"
        echo "Instructions on the download page for more information."
        echo "Please do not attempt to install this archive file."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "Can't find /usr/bin/sum to do checksum.  Continuing anyway."
fi
chmod +x $outname
echo "Extracting..."
./$outname
rm -f $outname #we dont need it anymore, so conserve disk space


if [ -z "${RPM_NAME}" ]; then
    if [ ! -d ${javahome} ]; then
        echo "Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of"
        echo "the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information."
        exit 1
    fi

    UNPACK_EXE=$javahome/bin/unpack200
    if [ -f $UNPACK_EXE ]; then
        chmod +x $UNPACK_EXE 
        packerror=""
        for i in $PACKED_JARS; do
            if [ -f $javahome/`dirname $i`/`basename $i .jar`.pack ]; then
                printf "Creating %s\n" $javahome/$i
                $UNPACK_EXE $javahome/`dirname $i`/`basename $i .jar`.pack $javahome/$i
                if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ ! -f $javahome/$i ]; then
                    printf "ERROR: Failed to unpack JAR file:\n\n\t%s\n\n" $i
            printf "Installation failed. Please refer to the Troubleshooting Section of\n"
            printf "the Installation Instructions on the download page.\n"
                    packerror="1"
            break
                fi

        # remove the old pack file
        rm -f $javahome/`dirname $i`/`basename $i .jar`.pack
            fi
        done
        if [  "$packerror" = "1" ]; then 
            if [ -d $javahome ]; then
                /bin/rm -rf $javahome
            fi

        exit 2
        fi
    fi

    PREFS_LOCATION="`echo \"${javahome}\" | sed -e 's/^jdk.*/&\/jre/'`/.systemPrefs"
    if [ ! -d "${PREFS_LOCATION}" ]; then
        mkdir -m 755 "${PREFS_LOCATION}"
    fi
    if [ ! -f "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.system.lock" ]; then
        touch "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.system.lock"
        chmod 644 "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.system.lock"
    fi
    if [ ! -f "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.systemRootModFile" ]; then
        touch "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.systemRootModFile"
        chmod 644 "${PREFS_LOCATION}/.systemRootModFile"
    fi

    if [ x$ARCH = "x32" ] && [ -f "$javahome/bin/java" ]; then
        "$javahome/bin/java" -client -Xshare:dump > /dev/null 2>&1

    fi

else
    if [ "$1" = "-x" ]; then
        echo "Extraction of RPM Done."
    else
        #  If rpm and the file exists then use rpm to install.
        if [ -f `pwd`/$RPM_NAME ]; then
            rpm -ivh `pwd`/$RPM_NAME
        fi
    install_JavaDB
    fi
fi
echo " "
echo "Done."
exit 0
```

Any idea about above issue , I guess some environment not pass into python , could not figure out what it is . as the bin can run directly ,but not through python subprocess

Comment: Also I tried to use absolute path instead of relative path on filename , same result .

Comment: Just did another try with remove shell-True , pass the command as list , still same . :(

Comment: Please add some code what you are doing with the Popen object. Are you using the stdout-pipe in your python code? The subprocess will block if it is full.

Comment: Thanks Thomas , you are right. I got poll() to print ouput , and when I remove it , works fine , not sure why it is block , any idea for printing standard output in this case . my code as below

while proc.poll() is None:
     output = proc.stdout.readline()
     print output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread actually answer the question:

[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

And it do solve my problem.

Thanks